# How to calculate the double integral of RBFInterpolater?

Tags: python, scipy

I need to use multiquadric to calculate the volume of the point cloud. When using the Rbf class, the dblquad function can be used to calculate the double integral. But with RBFInterpolator class, I don't know how to achieve similar functionality and the bugs appeared (picture below) :[image] Here is the Sample code:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

if __name__ == '__main__':
    points = np.array([[1, 4, 5], [2, 5, 7], [3, 6, 9]])
    # ** 1.Rbf ** #
    # 3d points, eg.[x,y,z]
    func1 = interpolate.Rbf(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], points[:, 2], smooth=0, function='multiquadric')
    volume1, _ = dblquad(func1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
    print(volume1)

    # ** 2.RbfInterpolator ** #
    func2 = interpolate.RbfInterpolator(points[:, 0:2], points[:, 2], smoothing=0, kernel='multiquadric', epsilon=1)
    volume2, _ = dblquad(func2, 1, 2, 3, 4)
    # print(volume2)
```

The picture below is a point cloud example. Grey points are original points sensor collected. Blue points are the points I entered in Rbf(multiquadric), and green points are the output results. But if you watch closely, you will find the green curved surface does not go through part of the blue points. The double integral in example code represents space volume above the green curved surface. My initial idea is using RbfInterpolator with smoothing=0 to see whether they can across. I am wondering whether there is a better way can solve this problem. Looking forward to your reply, really appreciate it!
[image]

Comment: Any three points are coplanar in a 3D space, so you have volume zero. If I understand you correctly you should use the volume of the convex hull. Or the enclosing elipsoid, or if you want the expected volume points in a gaussian distribution you should calculate that from the determinant of the covariance matrix.

Comment: @Bob Thanks for your advice. The points given here are just examples, in fact they are a bunch of point cloud data. I have succeeded with method 1 in the example code. What I don't know is how to calculate the double integral of RbfInterpolator with dblquad.